# Home/away teams with a list of players inside a backbone.js app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

**A. What level I am at: *intro*** I just finished a backbone.js course from "Jeffery Way". I am getting the hang of it, but how would I approach building an app that has say 4 teams (orange, blue, green, yellow) then 5-8 players per team?

---

**B. Describing the code:** Below is the code. I have a **`App.Models.Player`** model, an **`App.Views.HomePlayer`** and **`App.Views.AwayPlayer`** view, then there is a **`App.Collections.PlayersList`** collection, then a view for the collection **`App.Views.Players`** which displays each player model as a list, I render the same collection **`players = new App.Collections.PlayersList`** inside the home player view and an away player view. I am not sure how to associate them to a team? Do I create two collections, I don't want to create too many collections or too many views, I'm trying to figure out how to make this as minimal and readable as possible, I need some direction :) !

---

**C. Requirements:** Nothing too fancy here, I need a list of 4 teams, then 5-8 players per team(total of about 20-25 players, then need to associate them to a specific team) and I need to identify the current selected teams as either home or away. The home teams and away teams are interchangeable, I was thinking of having a list of the same teams on both side and hiding them, then the current teams that are playing will be displayed, I am just not sure if there is a better way than that?

*Final Word:* Yes I am using `window` for testing in chrome's console.log.. it will be removed when I get some momentum going.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>You have arrived.</h1>
    <div class="app">
        <button type="button"class="add">ADD</button>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js"></script>

    <!-- Templates -->
    <script type="text/template" id="home-template">
        <div style="float: left; width: 47%;">Name: <%= name %> - Points: <%= points %><button class="btn"></button></div>
    </script>

    <!-- Templates -->
    <script type="text/template" id="away-template">
        <div style="float: right; width: 47%;">Name: <%= name %> - Points: <%= points %><button class="btn"></button></div>
    </script>

<script>
$(function(){

    //Name spacing
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Router: {}
    };


/*** OUR MODEL OF A PLAYER... PLAYER MODEL then SINGLE PLAYER VIEW ***/

    // Player Model
    // ----------

    // Our **Player** model has `name`, `points`, and `rebounds` attributes.
    window.App.Models.Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
        // Default attributes for the player item.
        defaults: {
            name: "Michael",
            points: 10,
            rebounds: 9
        }

    });

    // Single player view
    // ---------------

    // This is a view of how a player should look.
    window.App.Views.HomePlayer = Backbone.View.extend({

        //el is a list tag.
        tagName:  "li",

        // Cache the template function for a single item.
        template: _.template($('#home-template').html()),

        events: {
            'click .btn': 'mikeAlert'
        },

        mikeAlert: function() {
           alert('get food');
        },

        // Re-render the titles of the todo item.
        render: function() {
          this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );

          return this;
        }

    });

    // Single player view
    // ---------------

    // This is a view of how a player should look.
    window.App.Views.AwayPlayer = Backbone.View.extend({

        //el is a list tag.
        tagName:  "li",

        // Cache the template function for a single item.
        template: _.template($('#away-template').html()),

        events: {
            'click .btn': 'mikeAlert'
        },

        mikeAlert: function() {
           alert('get food');
        },

        // Re-render the titles of the todo item.
        render: function() {
          this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );

          return this;
        }

    });

/*** END PLAYER MODEL SETUP ***/



/*** OUR PLAYERS COLLECTION... PLAYERS COLLECTION then PLAYERS COLLECTION VIEW ***/

    // Players Collection
    // ---------------

    // We connect the players collection to the player model
    // The collection of players is backed by *localStorage* instead of a remote
    // server.
    window.App.Collections.PlayersList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        // Reference to this collection's model.
        model: App.Models.Player

        // Save all of the player items under the `"players-backbone"` namespace.
        //localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("players-backbone"),

    });


    // Players Collection View
    // ---------------

    // Display a list of all player*s* here.
    window.App.Views.Players = Backbone.View.extend({
        // Instead of generating a new element, bind to the existing skeleton of
        // the App already present in the HTML.
        el: $(".app"),

        initialize: function() {
            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {

            this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);

            return this;
        },

        addOne: function(model) {

            //Create a new child view
            var homeplayer = new App.Views.HomePlayer({ model: model });
            var awayplayer = new App.Views.AwayPlayer({ model: model });

            //Then append it to the root, this
            this.$el.append( homeplayer.render().el );
            this.$el.append( awayplayer.render().el );
        }

    });

/*** END PLAYER*S* COLLECTION SETUP ***/


    // Dummy Collection, new instance of *App.Collections.PlayersList* 
    // ---------------
    window.players = new App.Collections.PlayersList([
        {
            name: 'McGee',
            points: '14'
        },
        {
            name: 'Joe E',
            points: '21'
        },
        {
            name: 'Mike',
            points: '8'
        }
    ]);



    //Create new instaces to initialize each view

    // New *App.Views.Player* instance, need to instantiate to set the model in the view.
    // ------------
    window.playersView = new App.Views.Players({ collection: players });


});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please ask any questions, it would be so cool to get some insight and finally working on a real world project, this could be fun for most and easy points!

**THANKS!!**

EDIT *updated array*: could I re arrange my array? if so, this changes the model, is this valid, how do I implement this? Any links.. advice this would be cool, I wouldnt have to create a new collection I wouldnt think. AHhh really new to this stuff so any tips would be comforting.

```
{
    "team":
        {
            "blue":
                [
                    { "name": "Mike", "points": 10 },
                    { "name": "Joe", "points": 13 },
                    { "name": "Kobe", "points": 23 }
                ]
        },

},
{
    "team":
        {
            "orange":
                [
                    { "name": "John", "points": 12 },
                    { "name": "Narlens", "points": 33 },
                    { "name": "MJ", "points": 22 }
                ]
        },

}
```

So I guess instead of creating a new collection/model etc I can just add that players team name then add the team name inside a class and only show that specific team and it's players.. here is the jSON array. Please if there is a better way, explain I am learning and got into backbone to have a better developer tools.

```
window.players = new App.Collections.PlayersList(
    [
        {   
            team: 'Green',
            name: 'McGee',
            points: '14'
        },
        {
            team: 'Green',
            name: 'Joe E',
            points: '21'
        },
        {
            team: 'Green',
            name: 'Mike',
            points: '8'
        },

        {   
            team: 'Blue',
            name: 'Eli',
            points: '14'
        },
        {
            team: 'Blue',
            name: 'Michael',
            points: '21'
        },
        {
            team: 'Blue',
            name: 'Tim',
            points: '8'
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: Did I word this question wrong? Are there any points I need to emphasize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Added the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ythLm/

Not sure if that's what you wanted to implement. I am assigning players to teams in this demo, which may or may not satisfy all your future requirements. (but we can always improve) :)

**===ORIGINAL ANSWER===**

I'm not sure I fully understand your requirements here...so you wanna display all the players in one view? and show their team names and sides? what's the order for the players list?

but:

to assign players to teams, you can just simply pass them as an attribute on the team model.

Oh yea, I think You need a team model:

```
App.Models.Team = Backbone.Model.extend({
    //team stuff
});

App.Collections.Teams = ... //usually you want a collection too
```

and then

```
var blueTeam = new App.Models.Team({
  name: 'blue team',
  players: new App.Collection.Players([
    {"name": "Mike", "points": 10 },
    { "name": "Joe", "points": 13 },
    { "name": "Kobe", "points": 23 }
  ]);
});
```

Home team and away team, or just currently selected team, can just be an attribute on the team model. When you want to change them, you can just change the attribute on the team model. eg.

```
var blueTeam = new App.Models.Team({
  //other attributes and players
  selected: true,
  side: 'home'
});
```

You can attach those status to collections as well, but I don't recommend doing that. (let's think if this is a real world application, Team has_many :players, and Player belongs_to :team)

but you want to have all the players in one list (if i understand your requirements correctly), so we need to assign Team to each Player, instead of assigning players to a Team:

```
var mike = new App.Models.Player({
  name: 'mike',
  team: new App.Models.Team({
    name: 'blue'
  });
});
```

but there's a problem with this: there are 20 players, but only 4 teams, you will have each team repeated 5 times, and they are all different objects. eg. if you do

```
mike.get('team').set('selected', true);
```

only mike's 'team' will be selected, other blue team players' "team" will not be updated.

to solve this.

First, get all the players altogether. remember, they need to a foreign key, or any kind of reference to the team they belong to: (it could be team_id, or just team_name)

```
var players = App.Collections.PlayersList([
    {"name": "Mike", "points": 10, team_id: 1},
    {"name": "Joe", "points": 13, team_id: 2},
    {"name": "Kobe", "points": 23, team_id: 1}
    //... all your players
]);
```

and then, your teams, but you don't have to assign players :

```
var teams = new App.Collections.Teams([
  {"id": 1, name: "blue team", selected: false, side: ''},
  {"id": 2, name: "red team", selected: false, side: ''}
  //... all your teams
]);
```

now, somewhere in your app assign teams to your players:

```
players.each(function(player){
  player.set("team", teams.get(player.get("team_id")));
});
```

doing it this way, makes sure all the players on the same team will have the same team model.

(Example http://jsfiddle.net/sbjaz/10/ when the code is paused by debugger, open your console, and try to play with player_1, player_2, and player_3, 1 and 2 are on the same team, try change any attributes on the team model for player1/2 and check the other one's team model)

(another Example http://jsfiddle.net/sbjaz/11/  do the same, you will notice when you update the team for player_1, player_2's team is not updated)

finally, in your collection view:

```
addOne: function(model) {
  var playerView;
  if(model.get("team").isHomeTeam()) {  //isHomeTeam is a helper method in team model
    playerView = new App.Views.HomePlayer({ model: model });
  } else {
    playerView = new App.Views.AwayPlayer({ model: model });
  }
  this.$el.append( playerView.render().el );
}
```

well, and you need to pass Teams collection to PlayerList view as well so you know if any of the team has changed:

```
new playersView = new App.Views.Players({ 
  collection: players,
  teams: teams
});
```

track team changes, in your view definition:

```
App.Views.Players = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.teams = options.teams;
    this.teams.on('change', this.render, this);  //if any of the team changes, rerender everyting
    this.render();
  }
});
```

and, you may think, this is not efficient at all: each time you swtich Home/Away teams, all the players will have to be re-rendered. how do I refactor this?

well first, I think you don't have to define two views for the player view -- they have too much repeated code! it's not DRY.

let's define a view that works for any player (at least for now):

```
App.Views.PlayerView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName:  "li",

  // events...mikeAlert they are all the same
  // you will see why we assign this.template in render instead of initialize
  //well or you don't have to assign this.template at all.
  render: function() {
    var templateSelector = this.model.isHomeTeam() ? "#home-template" : "#away-template"; 
    this.template = _.template($(templateSelector).html());

    return this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON());;
  }
});
```

you get the idea, or may be you don't even have to write two templates if they have too much repeated code too!

well you need to update addOne:

```
//since PlayerView's render() returns html directly...

addOne: function(model) {
  this.$el.append(new App.Views.PlayerView({model: model}).render());
}
```

now events, you don't have to pass teams to your PlayersView or bind collection change events there anymore.

in your PlayerView's initialize:

```
  initialize: function() {
    //rerender player view, when team is changed!
    this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
  }
```

now, every time you change any team, only the relevant playerViews will be updated.

Comment: Wow this looks awesome, thanks so much for the time and effort! You cant imagine how much I appreciate it... This may take awhile, I am a slooowwww learner...

Comment: I just saw your template (didn't see them when I was writing the answer), yea you don't even need to define two different templates.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. I may post a working jsfiddle later if my battery doesn't die.(or it's gonna be tmr)

Comment: Thanks so it makes sense just to set a team name attribute inside the player model? So should I load a list of all the home players in an div floated to the left `<div class="team home blue" style="display: block; float: left; width: 47%"><li>Mike</li><li>Joe</li>/div>` then away to the right `<div class="team away orange" style="display: block; float: right; width: 47%"><li>Kevin</li><li>Tim</li>/div>` set appropriate classes and show the playing teams? Or is there a better way to load them once and append the appropriate team list, this is something I need to think through.

Comment: I hope that makes sense. this is a stat app kinda like this image http://cdn.vertex42.com/ExcelTemplates/Images/basketball-stats-sheet.png Im in a basketball league and want to have an app to easily track stats, then post to a webpage or facebook with some api's, but I need to learn backbone.js lol (almost there) I made an app in PHP like this but I am using phonegap and decided to get into backbone for local storage and mobile apps. so I need to show the current away/home team then have a list of players so you can click a button to add points, assists etc.

Comment: The MVC style is perfect, but I am so noobish that I am not sure how to approach, that would be great to post a fiddle we can work on it. Looks like you got some points coming your way :)

Comment: in your case, it seems you don't want to update the view when the team switch sides? then I wouldn't put 'Home' or 'Away' on the team model since you want to track a player's history. If the sheet you posted is your goal, then my answer is not valid for this requirement. To me, each row in that spreadsheet is a record by itself, you shouldn't define them as PlayerView. You may want to rephrase your requirements and we will see how to model it. -- battery is dying...probably tmr. :)

Comment: Okay thanks, post back tomorrow I will try to rephrase my question. I may have to reopen a new one, if I do Ill post a link here. thanks again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42070/discussion-between-yurui-ray-zhang-and-michael-joseph-aubry)